# Stats on Various Aspects of Activity

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is it possible to get stats on user activity on the site.

- What times users generally come
- Are the question rates increase
- How much time users spend on the time
- How many new users are using the site
- Site events in hourly buckets
- etc.

Comment: This topic was kicked to the top of the 'active' list by '[Community](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)', probably because it has no accepted answer. If you accepted the existing answer then it wouldn't get kicked again. I suggest that the meta.buddhism site should ideally be about topic related to this site (Buddhism). For general questions about the web site software (which would be applicable to any/every stackexchange site) I recommend using http://meta.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of this information (but not all) is available to the moderators, but they are not allowed to share it. AFAIK the following is not tracked:

- Time users generally come (but you can see this for particular chatrooms [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com))
- How much time users spend on the site
- Site events in hourly buckets

Things that are tracked are for example:

- Number of new users
- Number of (new) visits
- Number of posts/questions/answers
- Number of votes

All these statistics are tracked per day (so not per hour), but again this data is only available to moderators.

What you can do is look at the site statistics on [the Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism). These are updated daily, but don't provide a history. On a few other sites some people have started to write down the statistics of the Area51 page every week or every other week so you can see how things are progressing, for example here are those stats for [Sustainability SE](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/99) and for [Personal Productivity SE](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/323/2132)